# Why are interneurons needed in the spinal cord for polysynaptic reflexes and somatosensory tracts to the brain?

Tags: pain, central-nervous-system, senses, reflexes

The single explanation I found for the polysynaptic reflex is that the interneuron diverges into more pathways, such as the efferent motor neuron, the inhibitory neuron to the opposite extensor muscle, and a ramification that goes to the brain. But why couldn't the afferent neuron axon solve for these ramifications? Furthermore, it is counterintuitive for a nociceptive reflex, that must save the damaging tissue as fast as possible, to be slowed down by an additional synapse.